# Error when update @adonisjs/ally version 2.1.3 to 4.1.3

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

After I updated @adonisjs/ally version from 2.1.3 to 4.1.3 and then I got error `Cannot find module 'Model`. I comment AllyProvider line and run again, It's not error but I can't login both facebook and google. I'm not sure, I do something wrong. (I use adonis 4.1.0) Thank for your suggestion. I spend many time for update adonisjs ally version to 4.1.3

**An error that I got.**
[image]

**I comment access provider ally in app.js**
[image]

**In my package.json**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check in the folder "node_modules" > "ally" if there is a folder "providers", if not, check if there is a folder "build" and check if inside it there is a folder "provider" and inside the file "AllyProvider.js" .

After confirming this folder structure, just change the code in "start/app.js" inside "const providers = {...}"
from: '@adonisjs/ally/providers/AllyProvider'
to: '@adonisjs/ally/build/providers/AllyProvider',

If it doesn't work, I advise you to remove the package and install it on version 2.1.3 which will work correctly with this configuration: '@adonisjs/ally/providers/AllyProvider'